# Can't validate Recaptcha in custom code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web, recaptcha

I have read in documentation about recaptcha, that there is possibility to test it on localhost. 
My problem is that I cant validate recaptcha in own code.

I need to add recapture to Razor MVC 4 web application, that is working now.

I did it in this way.

default.cshtml

```
 $.ajax({
                                    type: 'post',
                                    data: myForm.serialize(),
                                    url: "xrm/VerifyCaptcha",
                                    success: function (msg) {
                                        debugger
                                        if (msg.Success != true) {
                                            Recaptcha.reload(); // reloads a new code
                                            $('#alert').text('Введите текст картинки!');
                                        } else {

                                            var dataArray = { firstName: $('#input_firstname').val(), lastName: $('#input_lastname').val(), companyName: $('#input_companyname').val(), email: $('#input_email').val(), phone: $('#input_phone').val() };
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: 'get',
                                                url: 'xrm/register',
                                                data: dataArray,
                                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                                success: function (response) {
                                                    console.log(response);
                                                    $('#alert').fadeOut("normal");
                                                    $('#form').fadeOut("normal");
                                                    $('#information').fadeIn("normal");



 <div class="editor-label">
 Are you a human?
</div>
 <div class="editor-field">
 @Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.GetHtml("XXXXXXXXX", "blackglass","ru",0)
 </div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult VerifyCaptcha()
        {
            var valid = Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "XXXX");
            if (valid)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Message = "YES! Success!"
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = "Error!!!"
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

But `var valid = Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: "XXXX");` 
I have to do it through ajax call, because captcha is a part of validation mechanism on this site. 
Please help with the solution of this problem. 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

```
data: myForm.serialize(),
```

myForm wasn't a form element to my regret. It was just the table with the name "form". 
That was not my fault but it was my headache. 
Now all is nice and captcha looks good. 
Thanks a lot.